# useLocation can't be mocked with jest.fn() (while useHistory can be)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

What I'm trying is to write a test for a React component, using `useHistory` and `useLocation`, which looks like the following:

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function MyComponent() {
  let location = useLocation();
  let history = useHistory();

  function changeUrl(param) {
    // some logic here
    if(foo) {
        history.push(location.pathname);
    } else {
        history.push(param)
    } 
  } 

  return (<div>{/* actual elements here */}</div>)
}
```

Here's the test file:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ pathname: 'a' })),
    useHistory: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ push: () => { } })),
}));

it('should do xxx', () => {
    render(<MyComponent/>);
});
```

This results in

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined]
```

The error is originated from `location.pathname`. Meanwhile, `useHistory` doesn't throw any error.

Does anyone see what went wrong? Any advice will be appreciated.

---

**PS**

If I use `mockImplementation` within `it` like below, the error doesn't occur.

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ push: () => { } })),
}));

const { useLocation } = require('react-router-dom');

it('should do xxx', () => {
    useLocation.mockImplementation(() => { pathname: 'a' });

    render(<MyComponent/>);
});
```

I don't see why this happens...

Comment: I may have missed a part, but wtf is that ? : `function changeUrl(location.pathname) { ... }` ? I have never seen a function declaration like this one, this should be an argument here, not a variable to pass. You can directly retrieve `location.pathname` inside the function, why are you doing it like this ?

Comment: @RobinMichay Ah, sorry, this was not a good example. It's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mocking each hook individually, use [`<Memory router>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) instead

```
render(
  <MemoryRouter initial entries={['/a']}>
    <My component/>
  </MemoryRouter>
)
```

More examples in React Router docs, section [Testing](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing). Mocking individual hooks is less flexible.

Comment: I still don't know why `useLocation` can't be mocked... but this approach certainly allows me to run test cases. So I checked it as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Mocking hooks directly has some caveats. As a (kind of synthetic) example: imagine your code use `useLocation` and for whatever reason parse parameters on its own. And at some moment you decide to refactor it into `useParams`. If you mock hooks directly you will need to update tests. If you use `MemoryRouter` you will not need that - until you also change the logic.